# Deep Rails JSON parse

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, parsing

Is it possible to have `JSON.parse` work 2 layers deep so that a hash within a hash will get parsed as well? Is there a method for or do I have to do something like `JSON.parse(JSON.parse(...)['foo'])`?

Answer (score 1):

JSON.parse doesn't care about your `hash` structure:

```
> str = JSON.dump({foo: {bar: {baz: :qux}}})
 => "{\"foo\":{\"bar\":{\"baz\":\"qux\"}}}" 

> p = JSON.parse(str).with_indifferent_access
 => {"foo"=>{"bar"=>{"baz"=>"qux"}}}

> p[:foo][:bar][:baz]
 => "qux"
```

(Well, it cares if you have a malformed string, but that's something else altogether.)

So, what are you asking?